# what is the best approach to make an http request

Tags: http, delphi, delphi-xe7

what is the best method to do this: i have a txt file filled with web addresses, i have to check all of them using idHTTP component,only a simple check from a web server, downloading the html and finding a match, i want it to to be fast,  there is different types of threads and i am not sure what is the best to use, a `TParallel for` or `Task threads` or regular threads?
i tried before `TParallel for` and i got stuck at AV, also i've tried `Task threads` but its not fast, the http request becomes slower by time, i tried also the regular threads and i didnt know how to use it because its complicated to use.
note: Please do NOT downvote i just need advice from the experts. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "check"? Do you mean download the headers only? Check whether it's a valid URL or not? Check some of the data / contents found at that URL? Is your real question whether to use `TParallel` or `TTask` for your purpose? In any case, all of those are broad questions attracting opinionated answers - both of which are frowned upon here. What have you tried so far? What pros and cons have you yourself observed between these two possible solutions?

Comment: @JerryDodge Downloading the html and looking for a match, added infomramtion.

Answer (score 1):

First advice: do not use Indy. Use THTTPClient (unit `System.Net.HttpClient`) -- native for Delphi XE?+

I am still using old TThreads. I could make suggestion only with TThread.

Workflow:

Main thread -- reading your TXT file line by line. 
After line was readed, you create NEW thread, which are downloading information from WWW.

Sample of application:

```
unit ufmMain;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  { TThread }
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TLoad = class(TThread)
  protected
    FURL,
    FOutputFileName: String;

    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(const AURL, AOutputFileName: String); overload;
  end;

  HTTP = class
  public
    class procedure Get(const AURL: String; out AOutputStream: TMemoryStream);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  { THTTPClient }
  System.Net.HttpClient;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LLoad: TLoad;
  LFile: TextFile;
  LCycle: Integer;
  LUrl: String;
begin
  LCycle := 0;

  AssignFile(LFile, 'urls.txt');
  try
    Reset(LFile);

    while not Eof(LFile) do
      begin
        { Using for generate file name. All file names must be unique }
        Inc(LCycle);

        { Read next URL }
        ReadLn(LFile, LUrl);

        { Create new thread }
        LLoad := TLoad.Create(LUrl, 'Output file No ' + LCycle.ToString + '.htm');
        LLoad.FreeOnTerminate := True;
        LLoad.Start;
      end;
  finally
    CloseFile(LFile);
  end;
end;

{ TLoad }

constructor TLoad.Create(const AURL, AOutputFileName: String);
begin
  inherited Create(True);

  FURL := AURL;
  FOutputFileName := AOutputFileName;
end;

procedure TLoad.Execute;
var
  LResponse: TMemoryStream;
begin
  inherited;

  LResponse := TStringStream.Create;
  try
    HTTP.Get(FURL, LResponse);

    { Save result to file }
    LResponse.SaveToFile(GetCurrentDir + PathDelim + FOutputFileName);
  finally
    LResponse.Free;
  end;
end;

{ HTTP }

class procedure HTTP.Get(const AURL: String; out AOutputStream: TMemoryStream);
var
    LStream: TStream;
  LHTTPClient: THTTPClient;
begin
  LHTTPClient := THTTPClient.Create;
  try
    LStream := LHTTPClient.Get(AURL).ContentStream;

    AOutputStream.CopyFrom(LStream, LStream.Size);
  finally
    LHTTPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Why I against Indy:

1) THTTPClient do not required additional DLL for works with SSL protocol

2) THTTPClient is modern from Delphi XE8

3) My subjective opinion: THTTPClient works much more smoothly (with less issues) then Indy library. I used Indy for last 10 years, but now all my supported project moved to THTTPClient.

Comment: Why do you advise against using Indy?

Comment: @mjn42 -- Why I against Indy:

1) THTTPClient do not required additional DLL for works with SSL protocol

2) THTTPClient is modern from Delphi XE8

3) My subjective opinion: THTTPClient works much more smoothly (with less issues) then Indy library. I used Indy for last 10 years, but now all my supported project moved to THTTPClient.

Comment: @cyberdude -- yes, but that correct for all internet components.

Comment: you need to use some ONE component. you cannot use component A for login and component B to get request.

Comment: it turned out that TNetHTTPClient is buggy with handleRedirect and post, see here..[https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14671]

Answer (score 1):

You can use TTask and Indy (TIdHTTP). Example:

```
function GetUrl(const aUrl: string): ITask;
begin
  Result := TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      FOutput: string;
      FHTTP: TIdHTTP;
    begin
      FHTTP:=TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        try
          FOutput:=FHTTP.Get(aUrl);
        except
          // handle errors
        end;
      finally
        FHTTP.Free;
      end;

      TThread.Synchronize(nil,
        procedure
        begin
          ProcessOutput(FOutput); // send your output/result to main thread
        end);
    end );
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  list: TStringList;
begin
  list:=TStringList.Create;
  try
    list.LoadFromFile('yourfile.txt');

    // get all your urls
    // you should control how many threads run at the same time
    for i := 0 to list.Count-1 do
      GetUrl(list[i]);
  finally
    list.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't suppose that anyone will use it to read so many long sources. That is the place to process data. I will update it for you.

Comment: i used this method before, but this post response becomes slower by time if you are using multiple posts inside a loop

Comment: What gets slower? You did not provide any code how you use it. If you run too many threads and your computer can't open so many connection or the server can't handle it, it can be slower. But that is not a problem of this code. You can't DoS attack any server!